# I would like to add a range of dates to mysql database

Tags: mysql, sql, date, sql-insert

I wanted to know if you could add a range of dates into a mysql database instead of adding one date at a time. For example I would like to add the range of dates '01/01/2020 - 30/12/2020' and I would like to add this without entering each date on by one.

This is the only way I know how to add a date:

```
insert into tickets (departure_date) values (2020-01-01);
```

could anyone shed some insight?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming MySQL 8.0, you can use a recursive CTE for this:

```
insert into tickets (departure_date)
with recursive cte as (
    select '2020-01-01' dt
    union all
    select dt + interval 1 day from cte where dt < '2020-12-31'
)
select dt from cte
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=0478ca461b815c695505d902ef222954)**

Comment: I tried this and i'm getting the error 'unexpected keyword 'with' '. Any idea why this is?

Comment: @user10755614: this query requires MySQL 8.0. Which version are you running (`select version()`)?

Comment: i am running mysql 8.0.19

Comment: @user10755614: this query works in MySQL 8.0, as you can see in the demo that I provided in my answer (which runs under 8.0.19 too). Please run the query exactly as provided.